# I can’t type the number twenty on iOS

Tags: ios, bug, text-input

Since upgrading to iOS 15, I can no longer easily type the number 20. iOS automatically replaces it with 2.0, as shown in the screenshot. I don’t have a Text Replacement that would do this. Is this happening to anyone else, and is there a way to fix it?

[image: a screenshot of iOS suggesting 2.0 for 20]

Additional information: this is also happening on my wife’s phone. I used the search function to search for “2.0” on both of our devices, and we both have an app named “RTAGoMobile2.0” installed. I tried removing that app and `Reset Keyboard Dictionary`, but this behavior has not gone away.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iOS adds installed app titles to your autocorrect keyboard dictionary as part of the QuickType keyboard system. A lot of people realized this [when MARIO RUN came out](https://www.imore.com/its-me-mario-how-get-ios-stop-capitalizing-mario) on iOS. So the problem was probably originally caused by the RTAGoMobile2.0 app.

Since removing the app and resetting the keyboard dictionary didn't work, here are two two other things you could try:

1. You can train the keyboard to unlearn the correction by repeatedly typing "20" and tapping the x to remove the "2.0" suggestion.
2. You can add "20" as a text replacement, with "20" as both the phrase and the shortcut. Apple documents how to do that [here:](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207525)

> With text replacement, you can use shortcuts to replace longer phrases. When you enter the shortcut in a text field, the phrase automatically replaces it. For example, you could type "GM" and "Good morning" would automatically replace it.
>
> To manage text replacement, tap Settings > General > Keyboard > Text Replacement.
>
> - To add a text replacement, tap plus icon, then enter your phrase and shortcut. When you've finished, tap Save.
> - To remove a text replacement, tap Edit, tap "-" then tap Delete. To save your changes, tap Done.

Comment: I can type 20 now! I think it was a combination of deleting the RTA app, resetting the keyboard, and waiting an unknown amount of time. My wife deleted the app but didn’t reset the keyboard, and her phone was still typing the version number until she reset her keyboard.

Answer (score 15):

If you type out 20 20 20 20 20 and cancel the suggestion carefully each time, that might reset the learned database on the device that thinks it’s being helpful.

Also, I learned after posting this all app names are added to the “auto wrong” database, so you might struggle to “unlearn” those.

A good way to flush the predictive text on iOS 15 is the Reset Keyboard Dictionary tool in settings -> general

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207767

[image]

Once that is done, try to break the training by not accepting the correction. Also, check other devices you have signed into the same iCloud account in case these hints are shared between devices.

None of my devices do that for 10 or 20 or 30, so it’s likely trying to be helpful based on what you typed in the past and not something hard coded. Hopefully, you can dutifully correct the error each time it happens and the adaptive code will unlearn that “correction”. Sometimes auto correct feels more like auto wrong.

Unless Apple is pushing these “suggestions” from the server, you should be able to wrangle it. If not, a call to apple support might be needed - especially if they are seeding the corrections based on region or usage in general.

Comment: Don't you think that 'Reset Keyboard Dictionary' should work ?

Comment: I tried Reset Keyboard Dictionary, but it’s still happening. I have also tried typing “20 20 20 20 20 20” and it only offers the suggestion for the first 20, but it eventually comes back :(

Comment: @JacobKrall: Same issue with **"_its_"** (the possessive for **"_it_"**) on Android -- I keep telling the keyboard that it's wrong to make the replacement, but it doesn't seem to update.  I've been assuming that it's probably a case of a general rule (since most possessives are formed with apostrophe+"_s_", with "_its_" being an exception) that they'll probably take time to correct.  Is there evidence that `20`->`2.0` might be a general rule rather than a specific suggestion?  For example, does it do `30`->`3.0` , etc.?  Or "_2.0_" might be regarded as a suffix, such as in "_Web 2.0_"?

Comment: Thanks @tama that needed to be edited in. For it will help the retraining even if it doesn’t fix it immediately

Comment: It's unfortunately you have to break its training by not accepting it... i sometimes type in the middle of night and in the morning i have no idea what some words were supposed to be before autocorrect "fixed" them

Comment: It is @Michael I’ve had to turn off assistance for weeks when I just need to write and not have “assistance”

Comment: I can type 20 now! I think it was a combination of deleting the RTA app, resetting the keyboard, and waiting an unknown amount of time. My wife deleted the app but didn’t reset the keyboard, and her phone was still typing the version number until she reset her keyboard.

Comment: Yay @JacobKrall what’s an RTA app?

Comment: @bmike It was an app called “RTAGoMobile2.0” which I used to pay my public transit fare in New Orleans a few years ago.

Answer (score 4):

This autocorrect is **adapting to your patterns** of typing.  (that is why nobody else is having exactly the same problem).

It's designed to *learn* words like steerageway or deadfront which you use a lot, and "correct" a thing you're unlikely to type for something you're likely to type. I fully expect if I keep saying deadfront long enough, it will "fix it" when I say my phone has a dead front camera.

This tech *needs to be trained* and that requires that you dutifully use the on-word edit feature... the "X" to not apply autocorrects as they are being suggested, or the "rollback" button to undo corrects it has already done.  Those things *train the engine* and you need to do them.

Accessing the database is weirdly difficult. It appears the only way to train or delete words is to go into an application which uses this feature, such as TextEdit or a Safari text box, and type the word you are concerned with - so the on-word edit features will come up.  I can see where the files *live* on Mac ...

```
 ~/Library/Spelling/dynamic-counts.dat
 ~/Library/Spelling/dynamic-text.dat
```

... but I have not found a way to manage those databases in a tabular format the way you'd expect to.  I certainly wouldn't expect such a management tool to exist in iOS.

Comment: Thanks, Harper. I added some additional information to the question.

Comment: "Correct a think"? :)

Comment: @T.J.L.  One guess how that happened :)

Comment: I can type 20 now! I think it was a combination of deleting the RTA app, resetting the keyboard, and waiting an unknown amount of time. My wife deleted the app but didn’t reset the keyboard, and her phone was still typing the version number until she reset her keyboard.